# Should socrata/soda-scala be used for new Socrata SODA consumer development?

Tags: scala, socrata, soda

Given that

- it hasn't been updated in over a year
- there's no doc
- it's still dependent on Scala 2.9.2

I'm guessing that the [Socrata Scala SODA SDK](https://github.com/socrata/soda-scala) is probably dead or nearly so, and shouldn't be used for new (consumer) development - that the Java SDK should be used instead.  Correct?  I'm just making sure before I mistakenly invest time on the poorer choice.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with anything based on Scala 2.9. With something that old, you might have trouble finding *other* libraries that support it.